# Почему нельзя сделать return echo?

Tags: php

Конструкция `return require '/path/to/file.html';` работает

А при использовании `return echo $data['html'];` возникает ошибка

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Почему?

Comment: Потому что это ограничение языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [echo()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php) в php не имеет возвращаемого значения, а return ожидает получить параметр, который обозначает какое либо значение и void функция в этом месте указана быть не может. В отличии от него `require` может возвращать значение (согласно описанию конструкции [include](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить в переменную вывод из require, используйте буфер php:

```
ob_start();
require '/path/to/file.html';
$output = ob_get_clean();
```